# App closes after intent activity change - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have an image gallery on a Fragment and I want to create a program that, once the user clicks on a certain image, the program redirects the user to an Activity where more details are presented. However, after implementing the Intent, the program just crashes when the Activity opens.

I don't know what I might be doing wrong as I do not have much experience with fragments (I believe it is something I'm doing wrong in the fragment intent)

Here's the code:

Fragment

```
package cm.a12872_a18797.favlist.fragments

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import cm.a12872_a18797.favlist.ImageDetailActivity
import cm.a12872_a18797.favlist.Modal
import cm.a12872_a18797.favlist.R

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var rootView: View

    public val modalList = ArrayList<Modal>()

    lateinit var gridView: GridView

    private var descriptions = arrayOf(
        "Golden Bridge", "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", "Chevrolet Camaro",
        "Vegetable Casserole", "Sweet and Sour Chicken", "Design Vector",
        "Pork Loin", "Sidney's Opera House", "Pasta Dish",
        "Dope Setup", "Singapore", "Tacos Dish",
        "Toquio", "Warm Salad Dish"
    )
    private var images = intArrayOf(
        R.drawable.bridge, R.drawable.buccaneers, R.drawable.camaro,
        R.drawable.casserole, R.drawable.chicken, R.drawable.design,
        R.drawable.lombo, R.drawable.operahouse, R.drawable.pasta,
        R.drawable.setup, R.drawable.singapore, R.drawable.tacos,
        R.drawable.toquio, R.drawable.warmsalad
    )

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        gridView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_grid)

        for (i in descriptions.indices){
            modalList.add(Modal(descriptions[i], images[i]))
        }

        var customAdapter = GridAdapter(modalList, this@HomeFragment.requireContext())
        gridView.adapter = customAdapter

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener() { adapterView, view, position, l ->
            var intent = Intent(this@HomeFragment.requireContext(), ImageDetailActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("data", modalList[position])
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        return rootView
    }

    class GridAdapter(var itemModel : ArrayList<Modal>, var context: Context): BaseAdapter(){

        var layoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
            var view = convertView

            if (view == null){
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_grid_row, parent, false)
            }

            var imageViewName = view?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.grid_image)
            imageViewName?.setImageResource(itemModel[position].image!!)

            return view!!
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return itemModel[position]
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return itemModel.size
        }

    }
}
```

Activity:

```
package cm.a12872_a18797.favlist

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import cm.a12872_a18797.favlist.fragments.HomeFragment
import cm.a12872_a18797.favlist.fragments.ListsFragment
import cm.a12872_a18797.favlist.fragments.SearchFragment
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

class ImageDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val TAG = "ImageDetailActivity"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_detail)

        //region Bottom Navigation Menu =====================================

        val bottomNavigation: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)

        val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
        val listsFragment = ListsFragment()
        val searchFragment = SearchFragment()

        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.nav_home -> {
                    setCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
                    Log.i(TAG, "Home Selected")
                }
                R.id.nav_lists -> {
                    setCurrentFragment(listsFragment)
                    Log.i(TAG, "My Lists Selected")
                }
                R.id.nav_search -> {
                    setCurrentFragment(searchFragment)
                    Log.i(TAG, "Search Selected")
                }
            }
            true
        }

        //endregion ==

        val detailText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.detailText)
        val detailImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.detailImage)

        var modalItems: Modal = intent.getSerializableExtra("data") as Modal

        detailText.text = modalItems.name
        detailImage.setImageResource(modalItems.image!!)
    }

    private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment : Fragment) =
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.fl_wrapper, fragment)
            commit()
        }
}
```

Modal Class:

```
package cm.a12872_a18797.favlist

import java.io.Serializable

class Modal : Serializable {

    var name:String? = null
    var image:Int? = null

    constructor(name:String, image:Int){
        this.name = name
        this.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: please, also put the crash log in your question

Comment: Please add the exception logs and stack trace from logcat to your question